# Append the file extension in the file name if not given, in C++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm new to `C++`. I want to get the `fileName` as `command line argument`. User has to enter a `fileName`. If the user enter the `filename` without the file **extension**, then the program should add the the **extension** to the `fileName`.
I'm writing my code in `C++`. Is there a function or any method to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the actual problem adding a `".ext"` literal to a `std::string` variable?!? You can simply use the `+` operator.

Comment: Use the argument to initialize a [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and then you can use [std::basic_string::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) to locate the last `'.'` (if it has one), if not, just append the new extension. Most importantly, Bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) and use it. It is the best C++ reference on the internet.

Comment: You could use this to determine if there was an extension and to add one: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)

Comment: Take a look at `std::filesystem::path::replace_extension`,

Comment: @jkb That would replace an existing extension, too, which likely is not desired.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's fine, but you should first to look for the last slash or backslash, too, to cover file paths like `/some.directory/someFile`.

Comment: You could use [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/has_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/has_path) specifically `std::filesystem::path::has_extension()` to check first.

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right, I should have mentioned `has_extension()` as @drescherjm did.

Comment: @Aconcagua, of course, that wasn't provided as a critical interpretation of all corner-cases, cases to check, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `/some.directory/someFile` isn't a corner case! It's a perfectly normal filename.

Comment: You guys are somewhat funny. Instead of saying @DavidC Rankin (you didn't include X in your ***comment***), Just add, "You will also need to check for X". I'm not the one with the question and if you are nit-picking what doesn't fit in a comment -- you are barking up the wrong tree....

Comment: Thanks to all for the answer. It was really helpful to know the website and learn about many more new functions. I'm really grateful to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!(fileName.find_last_of('.') != std::string::npos)) {
    fileName.append(".ext");
}
```